# Jmeter with ant - reports creation

Tags: ant, jmeter

I am trying to create report using ant in jmeter, meaning the full report.
I downloaded ant and it is installed as expected.
first I want to understand if ant command need to perform after test plan ran in the past? meaning it is offline process that creates the html reports? after the test plan finished?
Or is it command that actually used to run the test plan and create the html, meaning I do not need to run jmeter before?.
I used this command

```
jmeter -n -t C:\JMETER\Framework\Test_Fragment\Kung_Fu.jmx -l C:\Users\stackoverflow\Desktop\Jmeter_reports\results22_05_2018.csv
```

to run jmeter from command line, and create csv, so do I need two commands? one for creating csv and one for the ant? and if I create the csv where can I find the jtl of the testplan.

Name of test plan kung_fu
name of csv results22_05_2018.csv

what are the processes to run he ant, since I rename the Kung_Fu.jmx to test.jmx and put it in extras folder and when I command ant, it says test.jtl is not found.

can someone give a full explanation about the whole process

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename `results22_05_2018.csv` into `results22_05_2018.jtl` and copy it to "extras" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Execute the following command in "extras" folder of your JMeter installation:

   ```
   ant -Dtest=results22_05_2018 xslt-report
   ```
3. HTML report will be available as `results22_05_2018.html`

For more details see:

- [build.xml](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v4_0/extras/build.xml) - reference [Ant build file](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html), by default it:

  - looks for `Test.jmx` file in the current folder
  - executes it and stores the result into `Test.jtl` file
  - applies [XSLT transformation](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp) to the `Test.jtl` file and generates HTML file out of it.
- [JMeter Ant Task](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)